# Delete all IndexedDB databases for website

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, indexeddb

How to clear all indexedDB databases on the page? 
I need some JS script that could be executed as part of Selenium webdriver test to wipe indexedDB data on the page totally.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not really reliable solution, and wasn't tested in Firefox:

```
indexedDB.webkitGetDatabaseNames().onsuccess = function(sender,args){
    for (let dbname of sender.target.result) {
        indexedDB.deleteDatabase(dbname)
    }
};
```

Would appreciate any feedback

Comment: webkitGetDatabaseNames is Chrome-only, not supported in Firefox, Safari or Edge. There's some discussion about adding a standard version https://github.com/w3c/IndexedDB/issues/31

Comment: If you know the database names, then simply avoid getting the database names. `deleteDatabase` itself is not the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Only because this came up when I was searching for exactly the same thing:

```js
let dbs = await indexeDB.databases();
for(let db of dbs){
    indexedDB.deleteDatabase(db.name);
}
```

Returns a list of databases that is then iterable.